# How to Create MYSQL Trigger with Conditionals and Left Joins?

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

So I have a scenario that I've been searching for tediously, but can't find a situation where both arise.

I have a Database where I want if a specific table is updated it executes a trigger to look at values within that Table artworkjobs_production and a second table artworkjobs. I don't agree with the manner that the structure of the data was created before I came on board; however I'd like to solve this without refactoring massive amounts of code.

Idea is once certain conditions are met I'd like the trigger to kick in and update a date per specific row being updated.

Here is the base trigger I've created, I want to know the correct syntax if possible to set this up as a trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER createProductionScheduleDate
AFTER UPDATE ON artworkjobs_production
FOR EACH ROW
  IF (((OLD.artworkjobs.deleted = 0) OR (NEW.artworkjobs.deleted = 0))
      AND ((OLD.Status = 'Approved' OR OLD.scheduleForProd = 1) OR (NEW.Status = 'Approved' OR NEW.scheduleForProd = 1))
      AND ((OLD.prod.isCompleted IS NULL OR OLD.prod.isCompleted = 'N') OR
           (NEW.prod.isCompleted IS NULL OR NEW.prod.isCompleted = 'N'))
      AND ((OLD.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') OR (NEW.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
      AND (length(OLD.invoiceNumber) > 0) OR (length(NEW.invoiceNumber) > 0))
     AND ((OLD.importance > 0) OR (NEW.importance > 0))
     AND ((OLD.quantity > 0) OR (NEW.quantity > 0))) THEN
UPDATE artworkjobs_production
SET originalProdScheduleDate = now();
WHERE ON LEFT JOIN artworkjobs_production prod ON prod.jobid = id JOIN tblaccounts ON acc_id = CustomerID;
END$$
```

NOTE: I played around and updated my syntax a bit but getting an error that the syntax is incorrect near the end.

Here is new code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER createProductionScheduleDate
AFTER UPDATE ON artworkjobs_production
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE artworkjobs_production
LEFT JOIN artworkjobs artworkjobs
ON jobid = artworkjobs.id
SET originalProdScheduleDate = now()
WHERE (((OLD.artworkjobs.deleted = 0) OR (NEW.artworkjobs.deleted = 0))
        AND ((OLD.artworkjobs.Status = 'Approved' OR OLD.artworkjobs.scheduleForProd=1 ) OR (NEW.artworkjobs.Status = 'Approved' OR NEW.artworkjobs.scheduleForProd=1 ))
        AND ((OLD.isCompleted is Null OR OLD.isCompleted = 'N') OR (NEW.isCompleted is Null OR NEW.isCompleted = 'N'))
        AND ((OLD.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') OR (NEW.printDueDate <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'))
        AND (length(OLD.invoiceNumber) > 0) OR (length(NEW.invoiceNumber) > 0)) 
        AND ((OLD.importance > 0) OR (NEW.importance > 0))
        AND ((OLD.quantity > 0) OR (NEW.quantity > 0)))
END;
```

Comment: mysql <> sql server. I assume from the syntax you are using mysql. The code will not be the same.

Comment: Sean <> is an acceptable operator in MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. I was saying that you have tagged this with both mysql and sql server. They are NOT the same thing. My comment had nothing to do with valid operators in mysql. It had to do with properly tagging your questions.

Comment: Ohhh I get it now, haha nice pun and I didn't realize that sql server was tagged.